# Monte Carlo estimation of Pi in Geogebra

Tags: sequence, montecarlo, pi, geogebra

I am trying to plot the Monte Carlo estimation of Pi in Geogebra.

I created a circle with radius 1, centered at the origin, and it is inscribed in a square.

To generate a sequence of n random points (determined by a slider), I added the following code in the input bar:

Sequence((RandomBetween(-1,1), RandomBetween(-1,1), i, 1, n)

The points appearing are only on the coordinates (-1,0), (1, 0), (0,1), (0, -1), and (0,0).

How do I get the points to appear on decimal values as well? For example (0.2, 0.4)?

Comment: You may consider using https://help.geogebra.org for GeoGebra related questions in the future to get quick answers from experienced GeoGebra users. I think they are a bit out of the scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RandomUniform](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/RandomUniform_Command) for this, i.e

```
points = Sequence((RandomUniform(-1,1), RandomUniform(-1,1)), i, 1, n)
```

with a recent version of GeoGebra [RandomPointIn](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/RandomPointIn_Command) will also work

```
points = Sequence(RandomPointIn(-1, 1,-1, 1), i, 1, n)
```

With either of those you can get the estimate of pi as

```
p = 4 * CountIf(abs(A) < 1, A, points)/n
```